# Query time-series column based on fixed time frame

Tags: c#, sql, timestamp, time-series, quantitative-finance

The first column is `DateTime.Ticks` value.

These values store every 5 minutes.

I want to query data in that column, based on a fixed time frame, e.g. **`H1`** ( 1h ) or **`M30`** ( 30 min ), as a user prefers.

How do I do this with a **`SELECT`** statement?

Update:
[image]

As you can see, all columns are based on ticks value. I want to query this table, based on **`timeofrefresh`** column and get rows inserted at **`H5`** basis ( in case of a 5 hrs TimeFrame or what ever other TimeFrame the a user selects ).

So, if a user has chosen an **`M15`** ( 15 min. ) as a TimeFrame, then these rows should be returned:

rows returned,
based on the  **`timeofrefresh1`** column values
and user-selected TimeFrame `M15` ( a 15 min. ):

```
22:30:00.016..., cell 2, cell 3, cell 4, ...
22:35:00.014..., ...
22:40:00.015..., ...

22:45:00.014..., cell 2,cell 3,cell 4, ...
22:50:00.016..., ...
22:55:00.014..., ...

23:00:00.015..., cell 2, cell 3, cell 4, ...
23:05:00.014..., ...
23:10:00.016..., ...

23:15:00.016..., cell 2,cell 3,cell 4, ...
23:20:00.014..., ...
23:25:00.015..., ...
```

....

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Too broad... See the [**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What SQL server? What technology to talk to the SQL server?

Comment: @NetMage SQL Server 2012 and a C# Client application.

Comment: As noted, images are not very useful way to post data in your question. Also, C# can talk to SQL in hundreds of ways - which way are you using? EF, LINQ to SQL, ADO, DAO, ...?

Comment: @NetMage I use ADO.net. I want to use T-SQL statement and put in the work on the Sql Server engine.

Comment: Your sample of what should be returned isn't rows, it is time stamps and I don't see matching rows in the data?